# Domain problems with my facebook login

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've created a HTML5 game that I run in my browser. I want to add facebook login, and copypasted stuff from the tutorial and replaced with my appId.

When I run it it states:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

The problem here is that I dont have a domain to run it under? My game is just running locally in chrome for now, but down the road I want to wrap it for mobile devices (android, ios, wp) using Phonegap or something

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+facebook+login

Comment: will [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) be help full?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it inside your localhost?
Check this post for more information, it might help you:
[Local Facebook App Development using localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731650/local-facebook-app-development-using-localhost)

Comment: Im running it localhost yes. As I said im developing and testing in Chrome now, but the goal is to create a Android app. I can't do javascript login like that? It only support websites?