# php redirecting to XAMPP folder

Tags: php, webserver, xampp

My problem is the similar to the one faced here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320205/why-does-my-xampp-installation-auto-redirect-to-http-localhost-xampp but unfortunately none of the solutions seem to work . I have done the following

a ) Consistently cleared the cache

b) renamed my index.php file in the htdocs folder to index_int.php .

I cant figure out why the redirection is failing . Do i need to make some changes in any of the config files as well ? I read in some post about prioritizing redirection . " The httpd.conf file is setup to prioritize .php files " Is it true . What should i edit in this file if that is the case .

Comment: Sounds like it's redirecting to the first virtual host that is set up. In your case this is the xampp folder. Have you set up any other virtual hosts?

Comment: @Baba & lix thanks i was ignorant about the acceptance thing . Thanks for helping me figure it out .

Comment: @Lix . This is my first time setting up localhost on my machine . Is there some additional config file changes that i should do . The other post i pointed out says this " The httpd.conf file is setup to prioritize .php files " . I am not sure what it means ?

Comment: @rockstar are you still have issues ??

Comment: @baba i have not been able to resolve it ..

Comment: The redirection is managed by `index.php` you would see something like `header('Location: '.$uri.'/xampp/');`

Answer (score 1):

Hello `XAMPP` has 2 index page one is `index.html` and the other is `index.php`

If you rename `index.php` it would not work because the back up would take over ... the `index.php` content looks like this

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $uri = 'https://';
} else {
    $uri = 'http://';
}
$uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header('Location: '.$uri.'/xampp/');
exit;
```

Just change the `/xampp/` to what you want  .. let me know if there are still issues

Comment: I am not sure if i want to edit the index.php to achieve this re-direction .                                                                      The problem is i am currently at /currentdirectory/index.php . Now i wish to go to /anotherdirectory/index.php .However instead the redirection is taking me to /xampp/index.php . So somewhere either my redirection in /currentdirectory/index.php is screwed ( which i checked is not ) or something else is preventing the redirection .

Comment: I used the xdebug to put breakpoints in /anotherdirectory/index.php but it seems i always hit the breakpoint at /xampp/index.php . Unfortunately at that instant the backtrace does not show sufficeint information for me . This convinces me more that maybe there is some more config change needed :/

Comment: Disable `xdebug` and run it normally first using `htacess` or `header`

Answer (score 1):

I think i should answer my question . i suspect the problem comes from the fact that i have not as yet configured my testing evirnonment to allow facebook to test apps locally. Here is the failing piece of code -

$facebook_login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $facebook_app_permissions, 'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri));

It works perfectly on a live server but does not on my local environment . I figured out that i need to set up Developing and Testing a facebook appl locally . Here are some posts about it [Developing and Testing a Facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365/developing-and-testing-a-facebook-application) .

I hope this saves someone time while debugging the seemingly mysterious redirection of xampp.